# Is my Cryptswap working?

Tags: boot, partitioning, home-directory, swap

I was receiving a message saying that cryptswap cannot be mounted. After several reboots, I do not have this message displayed anymore. Is it normal (see below) for 0 to be used?

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                  partition   6194172 0   -1

free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5875       1476       4398          0         50        731
-/+ buffers/cache:        695       5180
Swap:         6048          0       6048
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the outputs you provide, the cryptswap should be working. The `swapon -s` reports that you do have a 6 GB swap file mounted at `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` (lucky you, [for some this does not happen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377700/disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap-1-is-not-ready-tried-other-resolutions-al)).

The `free -m` output says that out of the 6 GB of RAM, only about 2.2 GB is currently being used and your swap is empty. This is OK since swap starts filling up only after the operating system has allocated most of the RAM to programs and cache.